# How to obtain trusted certificates for use with OpenSSL in C (on a Mac)?

Tags: openssl

I [asked a more specific question yesterday on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017890/where-is-the-certificate-file-for-ssl-ctx-load-verify-locations-in-openssl-locat) but haven't had any luck with responses. Basically I am trying to get OpenSSL wired up in low-level C with minimal dependencies. In that link I referenced some GitHub gist/repo examples of of OpenSSL C usage, but they are all incomplete.

What I'm stuck on right now is figuring out how to actually "secure" OpenSSL, haha. Surprising it [doesn't default to being secure](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-openssl/). So what I'm looking at code-wise is this:

```
if(! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/path/to/TrustStore.pem", NULL))
{
    / Handle failed load here /
}
```

The `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` function [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html) doesn't explain exactly (a) where to get the "trusted certificate store" or whatever, and (b) if not getting it then how to generate one using the `openssl` CLI tool.

What am I supposed to do here? How do I actually get to "securing" the thing? It seems that I need to obtain these trusted certificates somehow. (This is for an HTTPS *client*, not a server. I just want to make HTTPS requests). Am I supposed to hunt them down somewhere? (I am on a Mac). Or am I supposed to generate them with the OpenSSL cli? Or can the parameter to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` be null, and it just somehow picks it up from the source code somewhere automatically? Or is that what [this](https://github.com/darrenjs/openssl_examples/blob/a93a4e49d7825ffdacce4cb53307407f5804a081/ssl_client_nonblock.c#L36) is? (`ssl_init(0,0)`, which goes to [here](https://github.com/darrenjs/openssl_examples/blob/a93a4e49d7825ffdacce4cb53307407f5804a081/common.h#L298), to [here](https://github.com/darrenjs/openssl_examples/blob/a93a4e49d7825ffdacce4cb53307407f5804a081/common.h#L316) at `if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, certfile,  SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1)`, essentially passing `0` to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file`, but then again `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` is a different method from `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`, so not sure if it's related).

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenSSL traditionally cannot easily access the native trust store on Windows and Mac the common way for OpenSSL based applications on these platforms is to use the same set of trusted certificates as Firefox does, which also comes with its own trust store on all platforms and does not use the native one. This set can be downloaded at [CA certificates extracted from Mozilla](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). It then gets set with `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` for the specific SSL context as you already figured out (`SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` and related is for loading client certificates and not the  trust store).